# Unresolved reference: databinding

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using Android Studio Beta 1 with `Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.0-beta1` and `Kotlin Plugin 1.1.3-2`. I also have data binding enabled:

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

But unfortunately Kotlin classes don't see generated classes from layouts, cause I get errors like this one:

> Error:(17, 31) Unresolved reference: databinding
>
> Error:(39, 36) Unresolved reference: MyFragmentBinding

Of course Java classes see these generated classes.

Comment: Seem like puzzle with small input . Share your build.gradle it may help to come out for solution.

Answer (score 7):

Try adding kapt and apply the plugin in your module level `.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

//..

dependencies {
   //..
    kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:2.3.2'
   //..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this dependency in `gradle` for `Kotlin` to work with `databinding`

```
kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:2.3.3"
```